# c# forms multiple option using radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner coder in c# and i am having an issue with making multiple choices. basically i want the user to upload a text file with a list of URLs to be tested, (which i have working), then i want the user to be able to select which browser/browsers to perform the test with using the check boxes. and also if the test can run normally or using headless browser config. I have normal tests and headless tests working, but what i can't work out is how to make it so that a user can select which browser to perform the test with and make it so that it then runs it as a normal or headless test. I have attached an image of the form i have created and my form code(i have removed any non-essential parts). if for instance the user wants to select multiple browsers to run the test the code doesn't launch. i hope i have made sense of what i need help with but i have really pushed my coding knowledge to extremes with this and am at wits end

[image]

```
public partial class AtpTester2 : Form
{
    private IWebDriver chromeDriver;
    private IWebDriver foxDriver;
    private IWebDriver edgeDriver;

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    
    public AtpTester2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TopMost = true;
    }

    private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (NormalTestRBtn.Checked == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Normal Chrome Test Selected");

            foreach (string url in LSlistBox.Items)
            {
                //check if URL is valid
                Uri uriResult;
                bool result = Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
                //if valid URL call your OpenBrowsers method
                if (result)
                {
                    OpenBrowsers(url);
                    AccChromeTest();
                    CloseBrowser();
                    
                }
            }
        }
        else if (HeadlessTestRBtn.Checked == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Headless Test Selected");
            foreach (string url in LSlistBox.Items)
            {
                //check if URL is valid
                Uri uriResult;
                bool result = Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
                //if valid URL call your OpenBrowsers method
                if (result)
                {
                    OpenHeadlessBrowsers(url);
                    AccChromeTest();
                    CloseBrowser();

                }
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It won't work!!!!!");
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
            MessageBox.Show("Select a test option first", "Oops", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }

    private void UrlFilePickerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var filePath = string.Empty;

        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

       if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

            var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    LSlistBox.Items.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void ExitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void ClrLSBoxBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LSlistBox.Items.Clear();
    }

    //
    // Any other functions
    //
    public void OpenBrowsers(string URL)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Normal Button Starting Browsers");
        if (ChromeChkBox.Checked)
        {
            chromeDriver = DriverClass.GetDriver("Chrome");
            chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
            chromeDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        }

        if (FirefoxChkBox.Checked)
        {
            foxDriver = DriverClass.GetDriver("Firefox");
            foxDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
            foxDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        }
            
        if(EdgeChkBox.Checked)
        {
            edgeDriver = DriverClass.GetDriver("Edge");
            edgeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
            edgeDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        }
            
    }
    public void OpenHeadlessBrowsers(string URL)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Headless Button Starting Browsers");
        chromeDriver = DriverClass.GetDriver("Chrome Headless");
        

        chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
        chromeDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

        
    }

    public void AccChromeTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AccTest started for small test");
        string title = chromeDriver.Title;
        string url = chromeDriver.Url;
        Console.WriteLine(title + " :: " + url);

        AxeResult axeResult = new AxeBuilder(chromeDriver).WithTags("wcag2a", "wcag2aa").Analyze();
        //Creates the Chrome HTML report and sends it the reports folder
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath + "\\Reports");
        string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + "\\Reports", "AccReport.html");
        chromeDriver.CreateAxeHtmlReport(axeResult, path);
        Console.WriteLine("Report Printed");

    }

    public void CloseBrowser()
    {
        if (ChromeChkBox.Checked)
        {
            chromeDriver.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine("Chrome Browser Closed");
        }
        
        if(FirefoxChkBox.Checked)
        {
            foxDriver.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine("Firefox Browser Closed");
        }

        if (EdgeChkBox.Checked)
        {
            edgeDriver.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine("Edge Browser Closed");
        }

        
    }


}
```

}

Comment: The headless code doesn't seem to contain entries for Firefox etc, only chrome?

Comment: it will, i remove it when i am only testing code as it can take a while to complete the tests depending on how many sites it is testing and if i want to do a quick test of it then i don't want to have to wait too long. it is essentially the same as the chrome code

Comment: Have you checked the name of the CheckBox controls? Have debugged step by step to see if the code inside 
``` if (ChromeChkBox.Checked)
        {
          
  }``` 
is called?